# Starting and stopping a process

Tags: python

I am really having a hard time wrapping my head around multithreading in python. My expectation of the following code is that `appLoop()` will run for 10 seconds and the cease to exist -- which it does when tracing through in PyCharm, but not, when I just run it. This results in an infinite loop.

```py
import time
import multiprocessing

isRunning = True
runningSince = 0

def appLoop():
    try:
        global isRunning
        while isRunning:
            time.sleep(1)
            global runningSince
            runningSince = runningSince + 1
            print(f'Looping since {runningSince} seconds.')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f'appLoop stopped after {runningSince} seconds.')

class Process:
    class __Process:

        def __init__(self):
            self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=appLoop)
            self.process.start()

    instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not Process.instance:
            Process.instance = Process.__Process()

    def __del__(self):
        print('Instance deleted.')

p = Process()
time.sleep(10)
isRunning = False
print(f'isRunning set to False.')
del p
```

This brings up (at least...) 2 questions for me:

- why is `process` still running after `del p` -- am I creating a zombie process here?
- why does my `appLoop()` keep running even after I set `isRunning` to false when I run the app (according to my observations this works when tracing through the code as mentioned above)?

My use case in the end is to be able to start / stop my `appLoop()` from a flask web interface -- which is why I am trying to implement a singleton here. Just in case you might wonder...

And: I do know that `__del__` is not recommended as you never know when exactly garbage collection will call it -- in this case I just use it for (cave man) debugging.

Comment: When you do `del p`, it's calling `p.__del__()` in the background. Which prints `"Instance deleted."` and does nothing else. So that's why `process` is still running, probably

Comment: Right, that makes sense... What I *want* to do though is obtain access to the instance I already  made to terminate the process I started there.
That's where my confusion is -- how can I do this?

Comment: Guess, I was relying on code completion within PyCharm too heavily... Seems to work like this:
```python
    def __del__(self):
        self.instance.process.terminate()
        print('Instance deleted.')
```
Will do some more testing and post it as a separate answer if it works. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

`isRunning = False` changes the value of the variable in the parent process. The child process (the one that executes the while loop) has its own copy of `isRunning` that is not affected by the assignment.

For the same reason `del p` does not terminate the process: because it has its own copy of `p`. You should terminate the process explicitly in the destructor:

```
def __del__(self):
    print('Instance deleted.')
    Process.instance.process.terminate()
```

Comment: Correct me from wrong -- but when I do it like that, I am instantiating a new Process object in `__del__` as well -- which I terminate right away.
What I really want to do is get access to the already started process though to be able to terminate this one...

Comment: If you want to be able to access data and share it between the old process and the new process, you might want to look into just using `threading` instead of `multiprocessing` - the APIs are very similar.